# jssor slider clips images on Firefox 35.1 (#2)

Tags: firefox, jssor

With a recent release of Firefox (approx 18th Jan) jssor is now clipping images to varying degrees (bottom 20% - 50% of image).

A demonstration page can be found here https://erentz.com/jssor.php

Comment: It  happens with firefox 35 only. And it affects other sliders as well.

Comment: Many thanks, hoping that the folks at Mozilla are on the case.

Comment: This issue has been resolved with release of Firefox 36

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to Firefox 36.0 and the problem is solved at my site!